# How To Check Remote Application is opening Child Form or not

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-server

Let me explain my issues.
I want to kill the C# window application at the other PC. But, my problem is that I don't know the users are opening the Child form or not. Before I kill the application via Remote using WMI, I need to know that they are using Child form or not. If they are using, I cannot kill the application. So, I would like to know how can I check the Remote Application's Child Form using WMI. My code is below -

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var processName = "VPSBACKEND.exe";

        var connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();

        connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        connectoptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
        connectoptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
        connectoptions.Username = @"Moe";
        connectoptions.Password = "123";

        string ipAddress = "192.168.100.95";
        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + ipAddress + @"\root\cimv2");
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, connectoptions);
        scope.Connect();

        // WMI query
        var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_process where name = '" + processName + "'");

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get()) // this is the fixed line
                process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ask the user if they're using the form, if no response received in X time, close it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you don't mind, can you explain me in detail with sample?

Comment: It's just a concept for you to persue, I don't have a code sample or else I would have posted it as the answer.